# Set EJB jar file in manager server

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

Im new to weblogic Can you please advise how to set the ejb file in weblogic 11g console parameters for manager servers. I have to do the deployment of an EJB application.

Can you please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start the WebLogic Server Administration Console.
In the left pane of the Console, click Deployments and then click on Install
Locate the EAR, WAR or JAR file you would like to configure and then next
Select a Target Server from among Available Servers and then next->finish.

Comment: I have a dependency jar file (DS.jar) which needs to be set at the manager server (not the admin server) arguments. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Pal, You could deploy the DS.jar as library it is the radio button. You might be missed that option whil deploying it. Target can be AdminServer or ManagedServers or Cluster that you can mention as per your choice.[image]

Comment: I Installed the deployment as library option but it says application already deployed when i try to redeploy again. Please suggest how to delete and redeploy the same application.